# Spring Security Ouath2 JWT: Access is denied for authentication request

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

I've a Spring Boot side-project that uses JWTs to authorize users for hitting the end points: `/users/**` based on Authority in my Web Security Config as `.mvcMatchers("/users/**").hasAuthority("USER")`

I'm using Postman to test and following these steps:

(1) login using a REST Controller which responses with an access token (works fine as user is authenticated)

(2) with the access token, I chose Bearer Token in the Authorization in Postman and paste it there

(3) But I get 403 Forbidden in Postman

My question:

Why am I getting Access is Denied when the user has the authority `USER` in my database.

**Edit**

When I change `.mvcMatchers("/users/**").hasAuthority("USER")` to
`.mvcMatchers("/users/**").authenticated()` it works fine but I still want to use hasAuthority('USER')

I tried the following so far:

1. changed to 'ROLE_USER' in my db for the user
2. changed `hasRole('User')` in my Web Security Config

**Stack trace**

```
2022-10-25 08:24:37.190 TRACE 17964 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorizing filter invocation [GET /users/profile/] with attributes [hasAuthority('USER')]
2022-10-25 08:24:37.193 TRACE 17964 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.expression.WebExpressionVoter  : Voted to deny authorization
2022-10-25 08:24:37.193 TRACE 17964 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Failed to authorize filter invocation [GET /users/profile/] with attributes [hasAuthority('USER')] using AffirmativeBased [DecisionVoters=[org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@6ce8bf64], AllowIfAllAbstainDecisions=false]
2022-10-25 08:24:37.197 TRACE 17964 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Sending JwtAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt@4afa460a, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[SCOPE_USER]] to access denied handler since access is denied

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:73) ~[spring-security-core-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.attemptAuthorization(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:239) ~[spring-security-core-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
```

**My Controller**

```
   @GetMapping("/users/profile")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getUserData(Principal principal) {
        User user = userService.findUserByUsername(principal.getName());
        List<UserData> userData = userDataService.getAllUserDataForUser(user.getId());
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userData);
    }
```

**My Web Security Config**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JpaUserDetailsService jpaUserDetailsService;

    private final RsaKeyProperties rsaKeys;

    public SecurityConfig(RsaKeyProperties rsaKeys) {
        this.rsaKeys = rsaKeys;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .mvcMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/", "/about", "/register", "/test", "/login", "/loginrest").permitAll()
                .mvcMatchers("/users/**").hasAuthority("USER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/users/profile",true)
            .and()
            .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(rsaKeys.publicKey()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    JwtEncoder jwtEncoder() {
        JWK jwk = new RSAKey.Builder(rsaKeys.publicKey()).privateKey(rsaKeys.privateKey()).build();
        JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwks = new ImmutableJWKSet<>(new JWKSet(jwk));
        return new NimbusJwtEncoder(jwks);
    }

    @Bean
    DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        provider.setUserDetailsService(jpaUserDetailsService);
        return provider;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if a user has an authority in the database when you're using JWT *after login*, because authorities (roles) are fetched from the token itself - that's the whole point of using self-contained tokens.

So you should "guide" Spring and your `JwtDecoder` on how to search authorities in your JWT and convert them to `GrantedAuthority` to be used in `SecurityContextHolder`.
For that create and configure a bean of `JwtAuthenticationConverter` type:

```java
@Bean
public JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
    final JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter grantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
    // here choose a claim name where you stored authorities on login (defaults to "scope" and "scp" if not used)
    grantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthoritiesClaimName("roles");
    // here choose a scope prefix (defaults to "SCOPE_" if not used)
    grantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix("");

    final JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
    jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(grantedAuthoritiesConverter);
    return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
}
```

This configuration will allow `JwtDecoder` to convert any authority in the *"roles"* claim of JWT to `GrantedAuthority` with no prefix.